# Extract matching set of strings from source string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string like below:

```
<Ohter><Nodes><ErrorInfoList><ErrorInfo><ErrorCode>0001</ErrorCode><ErrorContext i:nil="true" /><ErrorMessage>New Error: Pending Need .</ErrorMessage><Severity>1</Severity></ErrorInfo><ErrorInfo><ErrorCode>0001</ErrorCode><ErrorContext i:nil="true" /><ErrorMessage>New Error: Pending Need -.</ErrorMessage><Other><Nodes>
```

I want to extract ErrorCode and ErrorMessage from this string. There can be many such instances in the source string. I am using c# to apply regex.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 3):

use this:

```
(?<=ErrorCode>)([^<]+).*?<ErrorMessage>([^<]+)
```

you will get the error code in \1 and the error message in \2

demo here  : http://regex101.com/r/bU3pW7

Comment: Thanks a lot aelor. You save me.